# progress bar without percent

Tags: html, css

Here's the problem :
i have a value and a maximum and i want to display them like in progress bar (except there's no progress :-) : the value is displayed as a bar whose width is relative to the maximum.

I cannot do this with a percentage :

```
<div class="bar"><div class="bar-content" style="width:xx%"></div>
```

because i only know the value and the maximum, i don't "know" the relative value in percent. 
I'm aware i could use some javascript or do something on the server side but i'd rather use **css and html only**.

I can't figure out something so now i'm looking for a good idea.

I'll try to explain more specifically : i have a value (say 20) and a max (say 80) and i want to display the value as bar whose width is 20/80 = 25% of the width of its container. I want to do that only using HTML, CSS, 20 (the value) and 80 (the maximum). I have no data other than the value and the maximum so i cannot compute the percentage because i don't want no javascript or server side programming.

I think this is not possible but we never know.

Comment: so calculate the percent before setting the style: `value/maximum * 100`

Comment: if you know max-value, use it on bar and use % on bar-content ? or is there a reason why you cannot do that ?

Comment: i edited the question to explain my problem a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
style="width: -prefix-calc(20/80 * 100%)"
```

This should work in all modern browsers including internet explorer.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aN9WW/

Comment: The point is this is never necessary. You have put those values, 20 and 80, into your css. Therefore you know them in advance. Therefore, you can do this calculation in advance, and just put the percentage straight into your css. Job done.

Comment: @davnicwil I don't why he does not want to do that in the server side (I am confused too) But this is what his question about, and this is the answer to that question.

Comment: i do not want to do that server side because each "progress bar" is generated in a loop. If i had to do that server side, i'd have to do the loop twice since i would know the maximum value only once the first loop is done.

Comment: @Derek, yep fair enough, it's a totally correct solution. But since the OP is clearly generating this css server side, I was just pointing out it probably makes most sense just to do the calc there - will make for cleaner css at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

You've sort of answered your own question, except you've assumed your answer is wrong. It's not. You should do this with a percentage in your css.

If you know the value and maximum in advance, then by definition you know the percentage width of the inner `<div>` in advance because it's a function of value and maximum.

Comment: you're right, i hate to use style attribute but how would you do in this kind of context where the css property can have any arbitrary value ? i mean i cannot create 100 css classes for 0% to 100% ?

Comment: Quite right, external static css is inappropriate in this case as you need dynamic values. Edited :)

Answer (score 1):

you have in HTML5 a tag for this :

```
<progress value="20" max="80">20<progress/>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rejdJ

Comment: nice solution. but the calc() one seems to be working in more browsers.